# Getting time in Time format

Tags: android, time

I am currently trying to work with Location updating.

I've been using the below to work out the time-stamps of when the last update was processed:

```
String NewLocationTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

However, to work out the difference between two times, I needed to parse it to a Time format. However, for some reason the Android Studio didn't recognize the DateTimeFormatter, and because I don't know in what format the String is going to come up, I am not quite sure what to put in the formatting either.

I believe it would be much easier if I was to be able to get a Time object straight away, so I can use something like:

```
long diffInMinutes = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime1, dateTime2).toMinutes();
```

Can anyone tell me how I get the Time object straight away, or why the Android Studio does not recognize the DateTimeFormatter?

Thank you

Comment: You are mixing old and new date APIs. Stick to one of them. Depending on need, to get "time" object directly, use `new Date()` (old API), `LocalTime.now()` (new API, time-of-day only), `LocalDateTime.now()` (new API, date+time), `ZonedDateTime.now()` (same but with DST support), or `Instant.now()` (global UTC date+time).

Answer (score 1):

Use `new Date().getTime()` and what you get is the time in milliseconds and you can work with it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Date` and use `Date.getTime()` for difference calculation. I do though recommend [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Also look at [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

`Time` an sql aware wrapper around `Date` and there is no such thing as `DateTime` or `DateTimeFormatter`.